# How to determine the winner in TicTacToe (Java)

Tags: java

For my homework I have to make a method which inspects the TicTacToeArray variable and determines if anyone has won. In particular, there is a winner if any column, row, or major
diagonal of the game board is filled entirely with Xs or Os. When a winner is detected
scoreTTT() should set the winner variable to "X" or "O", depending on who has won. If neither X or O has won, the winner variable should hold "*".

So far, I have this:

public class TicTacToe{

```
public static void main(String[] args){



}

//state variables
static char[][] TicTacToeArray;  //the game board
static int step = 0;             //the current step number
static char winner = '*';        //who has won (X/O/*)        *=nobody
static char player = 'X';        //whose turn it is (X/O)   *=nobody

//Creates a game board of size n x n and resets state variables to
//their initial conditions for a new game.
public static void startTTT(int n){
    TicTacToeArray = new char [n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
            TicTacToeArray [i][j] = '*';
    }
}

step = 0;
winner = '*';
player = 'X';
```

}

```
public static void displayTTT(){
    String row;

    int n = TicTacToeArray.length;

    //now I'm priting row0
    row = "       Column";
    System.out.println(row);

    //row 1
    row = "       ";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        row = row + " "+ i;

    }
    row = row + "  TicTacTow";
    System.out.println(row);

    //row 2
    row = "      +";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    row = row + "--";

    }

    System.out.println(row +"  Step = " + step);

    //row 3
    row = "    0 |" ; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    row = row + " " + TicTacToeArray [0][i];
    }
    System.out.println(row + "  Player = " + player);

    //row 4
    row = "Row 1 |";
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    row = row + " " + TicTacToeArray[1][i];
    }
    System.out.println(row);


    //row 5
    row = "";
    for( int i=2;i<n;i++){
    row = "    " + i + " |" ;
        for( int j=0; j < n; j++){
    row += " " + TicTacToeArray[i][j];
    if (j == n)
    System.out.println(row);

    }
    if(i == n-1)
    row += "  Winner = " + winner;
    System.out.println(row);
    }



}

//Updates a position on the game board, increments the step counter,
//and toggles the player from X to O (or vica versa). This method should
//test for invalid input (see assignment document) before changing
//the game state. If no error is encountered, it performs the update
//and returns true. Otherwise it returns false.
public static boolean updateTTT(char sym, int row, int col){
    if (sym != 'X' && sym != 'O'){
            return false;
    }
    if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= TicTacToeArray.length || col >= TicTacToeArray.length){
            return false;
    }   



    if (TicTacToeArray[row][col] == '*')
    TicTacToeArray [row][col] = sym;
    else
    return false;

    // toggle player
    for(;;){
    if (player =='X'){
    player = 'O';
    break;
    }
    if(player == 'O'){
    player = 'X';
    break;
    }
    }
    //inc step count
    step +=1;


    return true;
}
```

//(This is commented out/what I have so far for this method, the rest of the code should work however)
    //public static void scoreTTT(){

```
//for(int i=0; i < TicTacToeArray.length; i++){
    //for(int j =0; j < TicTacToeArray.length; j++)
    //if (TicTacToeArray[i][j] ==  TicTacToeArray[i][j+1])




}
```

I think I need to make 3 different nested loops which check for both diagonals and then the rows/columns, they must also check for a full row/column for any array size, such as 4 x 4. I'm just not sure how I would go about making the loops go through the entire row/column/diagonal. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you have three different cases.

First check all of the columns, then check all of the rows, then check the diagonals.

The first should be a loop (for each column, check each row).
The second should be like the first (just reverse column and row).
The third case is easy, you only have two options, the top-left to bottom-right and the top-right to bottom-left.  Just make sure that all of the corresponding boxes are equal.

I would give more specific detail, but it is homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[][] board = new char[][] {
        {'x', 'o', 'x'},
        {'x', 'o', 'o'},
        {'o', 'o', 'x'}
};

//check rows/cols
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    String row = "";
    String col = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        row += board[i][j];
        col += board[j][i];
    }
    System.out.println("Row: " + row);
    System.out.println("Col: " + col);
}

//check diagonals -- the logic in this loop could be folded into the previous one
String diag1 = ""; //top-left to bottom-right
String diag2 = ""; //bottom-left to top-right
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    diag1 += board[i][i];
    diag2 += board[board.length-i-1][board.length-i-1];
}
System.out.println("Diag1: " + diag1);
System.out.println("Diag2: " + diag2);
```

You will have to work out how to check for the winner.